# Reset Form After Angular $http success

Tags: angularjs, forms, http, reset

I am wondering how I can clear the contact object after a successful $http POST?  The code is erroring out at the `this.contact = {};` in the success callback.

```
angular.module('kbtApp')
  .controller('ContactFormCtrl', function ($scope, $http, toaster) {
        var that = this;
        this.status = false;
        this.contact = {
            'fullname': 'Jim Rainaldi',
            'email': 'jtrainali@gmail.com',
            'organization': 'Jamesrainaldi.com',
            'position': 'Web Guy',
            'message': 'This is just a test.'           
        };
        this.contact.isAjax = true;

        this.sendEmail = function(){
            var status = null;
            var statuss = $http({
                url: "/scripts/php/sendEmail.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: this.contact
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                this.contact = {}; 
                toaster.pop('success', "Success", 'Your message has been sent.', 7500, 'trustedHtml');
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //$scope.status = status;
                toaster.pop('error', "Error", 'Email failed to send.', 7500, 'trustedHtml');
            });

        };

  });
```

Comment: Change `this.contact` to `that.contact`.

Comment: why not just use `$scope`?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in the success callback I typed $scope in dev tools and it came back undefined.

Answer (score 0):

@raina77ow was correct.  I updated this.contact = {} to that.contact = {}